# Local Security Policy Cannot Change Security Level

Tags: windows, group-policy, security-policy, local-groups

Today when I was testing Local group policy I set security level disallow to

> Set as default

Now the button is disable and I am unable to run any kind of executable in my pc.

[image]

and see this message when run an executable
[image]

Luckily I have opened command prompt prior to this as admin now but still I cannot run any program using start command.

Please help how can I toggle this feature.

Comment: Log into the built-in Administrator account.  You might have to enable it.  You should be able to reverse the group policy you enabled.  If that does not work, then modify the registry key associated with the group policy, within WInRE.

Comment: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Safer` should be registry key responsible for the local group policy.  Please provide the relevant information from that key as you currently have it configured.

Comment: thankyou @Ramhound the problem was solved ,actually there is an unrestricted policy which negate the above and that was not disable so by using that policy all is well now.

Comment: You should submit a full detailed solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting **Unrestricted** "Set as default", this is because when you set **Disallow** "Set as default" the "Set as default" button inside **Unrestricted** automatically turn enable which is the negation of **Disallow** policy.

So just click set as default inside **Unrestricted** will solve the problem.
Here is how it works
[image]

[image]